# Indefinite Integration of Algebraic Equation

Tags: calculus

How to integrate the following equation.

$$\int\frac{1}{2x-x^2}dx$$

I tried solving this but I am not able to convert this into a form where I can apply integration formula.

Comment: $$2x-x^2=x(2-x)$$ So numerator  $$\dfrac{x+2-x}2$$

Comment: Completing the square is always good in cases like these

Comment: denominator of integrand is $ 1- (1-x)^2 $ and numerator is $- d(1-x) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x-x^2=-(x^2-2x)=-(x^2-2x+1-1)=1-(x-1)^2$

Now substitute $t=x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int { \frac { 1 }{ 2x-{ x }^{ 2 } }  dx} $ = $\int { \frac { 1 }{1-({x-1}^{ 2 } )}  dx} $ now let u = x-1 then the integral will become $\int{\frac{1}{1-u^{2}}du} = \int{\frac{1}{2(u+1)}+\frac{1}{2(1-u)}}$ = $\frac{1}{2}(log(x)-log(2-x))+constant$

Answer (score 0):

By completing the square, any quadratic polynomial can be reduced to a form

$$b+az^2.$$

Then by rescaling (assuming $b\ne0$)

$$1\pm t^2.$$

Now

$$\frac1{1+t^2}=(\tan^{-1}t)'$$ is the derivative of the arc tangent, while

$$\frac1{1-t^2}=(\tanh^{-1}t)'$$ is the derivative of the argument of the hyperbolic tangent.